# Countable cartesian product and Axiom of Choice

Tags: set-theory, axiom-of-choice

In the *A taste of Topology* book, when talking about Cartesian product $\prod\{S:S\in\mathcal{S}\}$, the author [writes the following](https://books.google.com/books?id=BUzOSed1sEEC&pg=PA18):

> It is straightforward that $\prod\{S:S\in\mathcal{S}\}\neq\emptyset$ 
>   whenever $\mathcal{S}$ is finite and $S\neq\emptyset$ for any 
>   $S\in\mathcal{S}$. *The same can be shown if $\mathcal{S}$ is
>   countable*, see  Exercise 2.

The "[Exercise 2](https://books.google.com/books?id=BUzOSed1sEEC&pg=PA20)" asks to prove that $\prod_n S_n$ of non-empty sets is non-empty, without invoking Zorn's lemma.

Is it indeed that straightforward to show the claim for countable $\mathcal{S}$? I was under the impression that while the full strength of AC is not needed, one still needs the weaker Axiom of Countable Choice to make that claim. Can it be proved in ZF alone?

Comment: I think this indeed a small mistake in an overall very nice textbook. At the very least, there is no clue in the text about the solution the author may have had in mind.

Comment: You can prove this "Exercise 2" *without invoking Zorn's Lemma* (equivalent to full AC), but you need at least countable AC to prove the statement — in fact it's equivalent to that.

Comment: Agreed, it's a bit cagey and evidently confusing.

Comment: @Brian: Actually this concerns a countable family of finite sets. So it's much weaker than countable choice. It is equivalent to König's lemma about trees.

Comment: @AsafKaragila, ah and oops, I totally overlooked that the sets $S\in\mathcal{S}$ remain finite. Yes, a good bit weaker than full-blown countable choice, and equivalent, as you note, to "every infinite finitely-branching tree has an infinite branch". In any case, not a theorem of ZF.

Comment: I don't know anything about this textbook or its author, but I do personally know a professor who would be perfectly happy to make countably many choices in a proof and think there's no axiom of choice involved. He even tricked me into doing the same without realizing it, at a time when, though I hadn't had much formal instruction on choice, I was familiar with it from recreational reading, and feel I should have known better. It's an easy trap to fall into until you remember a proof cannot have countably infinitely many steps.

Comment: @DustanLevenstein I think the confusion stems from the impression that the "choice" in the countable case resembles  induction, but in fact induction can be used only in finite case. However, one can still made countably many choices if all sets are identical (I think), and that's a pretty common occurrence.

Comment: @Markus That's an interesting take on it that I hadn't really thought about before; it's a common pedagogical technique for professors to unravel an induction proof by giving the proof of the base case, and then the first few induction steps, until the students catch on to the pattern.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on the information you provide this is a mistake. You are correct in that it is consistent that there is a countable family of finite sets whose product is empty (namely, they do not have a choice function).

For example in Cohen's second model for the failure of choice there is such family of sets of size $2$.

Comment: Is the statement true in a more concrete setting, for example if $S_n$ are non-empty subsets of $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: Yes. There you can always choose from finite sets uniformly (even from uncountably many): since every finite set of reals has a minimum you can choose that one.

Comment: So pick $F_n\subset S_n$ finite, and since $\Pi F_n$ is non-empty, so is $\Pi S_n$? This would work then for any subsets of an well-ordered set, right? Edit: This can be right. Doesn't "picking" finite subsets $F_n$ already involve some choice?

Comment: You are correct. Choosing the finite subset requires choice. Because why not just choose a singleton, or just its element directly.

Comment: Then  how do you choose "from finite sets uniformly", since $S_n$ might not be finite? I see it when $S_n$ are finite, or when $S_n$ are well-ordered (always choose the least element).

Comment: Then you have to invoke the axiom of choice in one form or another.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34182/discussion-between-markus-and-asaf-karagila).

Comment: Sorry, I don't like the chat here very much so I don't use it unless really necessary; and I have to prepare a class and go teach now anyway.

Comment: I misunderstood your statement, sorry for the confusion. So the statement is true when $S_n$ are finite subsets of $\mathbb{R}$, but when they are infinite one still may need some form of choice. I had the impression you claimed the statement is true for any non-empty subsets of $\mathbb{R}$.